# Multiple ajax request in php with different data each request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hello fellow developers!

Is multiple ajax request the right thing to do when I want my PHP web-app to multi-thread? or is there any method or library that could help me?

And is it possible in multiple ajax request to have different data for each request?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use this : [React PHP](https://reactphp.org/)

From the site:

> ReactPHP is a low-level library for event-driven programming in PHP.
>   At its core is an event loop, on top of which it provides low-level
>   utilities, such as: Streams abstraction, async dns resolver, network
>   client/server, http client/server, interaction with processes.
>   Third-party libraries can use these components to create async network
>   clients/servers and more.

Comment: Thank you for sharing the site. I will try to look at it.